# Flask returning html page while processing another fx which takes long to load

Tags: python, selenium, flask, screenshot, background-task

I am working on a Flask web app with selenium. It accepts a URL as input does some calculations on various items then takes a screenshot of that page, however, the screenshot part is taking at least 5-7 seconds and really depends on when their website fully loads.

I can't wrap my head around how to load the page with the calculations but pass off the screenshot part until after the new page with the calculations has loaded; Potentially just showing a loading gif in the area where the image would show.
I thought about rendering the template with just the calculations and then on page load via ajax, submit the fx for the image, via jquery run a loading gif in place of the image and then refresh the page every x seconds via jquery till it's done but it seems like bad practice any input/comments are greatly appreciated.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # bunch of calcs happen first
    imgofsite = ''
    driver.set_window_size(width=800, height=600)
    driver.get(site)  # whatever reachable url
    timeout = time.sleep(5)
    if not error:
        name_it = str(site)
        apng, seppng, namepng = name_it.partition('//www.')
        time.sleep(2)
        if os.path.isfile(namepng.lower().replace('/', '-') + '.png'):
            pass
        else:
            driver.save_screenshot('./static/' + name.lower().replace('/', '-') + '.png')

            imgofsite = namepng.lower().replace('/', '-') + '.png'
```

Comment: You can wait for visibility of specific element before taking screenshot. What exactly you want your screenshot to capture? Which element?

Comment: You can start an AJAX to get the the calculation and when it returns, start another AJAX to get the screenshot part, then it will wait for response while it'll get the results. If I got your question.

Comment: It is taking a screenshot of the entire website. What Im trying to figure out is the best solution for moving on to the next page then run the fx to capture the screenshot. Potentially have to use celery